# Prove that $(n+\sqrt n)^{1/2}$ is irrational for every $n\in\Bbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, rationality-testing

Prove that $(n+\sqrt n)^\frac{1}{2}$ is irrational for every $n\in\Bbb N.$

I guess the only thing I can do here is assume the opposite, i.e. $(n+\sqrt n)^\frac{1}{2}=\frac{p}{r}$ and somehow see the contradiction. If I square both sides I get $n+\sqrt n=\frac{p^{2}}{r^{2}}$ and now I don't know what to do next.

Comment: You need a fact: the square roots of natural numbers are either irrational, or integers. From this, you can use your argument to conclude that $\sqrt{n}$ is rational, hence $n$ is a perfect square.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $n$ is a perfect square ($n=k^2$), the expression reduces to $\sqrt{k^2+k}$ for $k\in\Bbb N$. However, $k^2<k^2+k<(k+1)^2$, so $k^2+k$ is not a perfect square and $\sqrt{n+\sqrt n}$ is irrational.

If $n$ is not a perfect square, assume $\sqrt{n+\sqrt n}$ to be rational. Then $n+\sqrt n$ and therefore $\sqrt n$ are rational, since rational numbers are closed under the four operations. But since $n$ is not a perfect square, $\sqrt n$ is irrational and a contradiction arises. Hence $\sqrt{n+\sqrt n}$ is irrational.

Comment: How did you get  $k^2<k^2+k<(k+1)^2$, so $k^2+k$ is not a perfect square

Comment: @Now_now_Draco_play_nicely Because $k^2$ and $(k+1)^2$ are _consecutive_ perfect squares.